# CSS relative positioning not breaking line

Tags: css, css-position

i want to have a relative positioning of some divs, having an outer container and floating in **one** line.

The only way to achieve this is to float left i think right?
But if i do so, it will break in a new line if the elements are larger than the containers width...

here the code:
(please do not mind syntax-error)

```
<div style="position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;overflow:scroll">
 <div id="1" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
 <div id="2" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Div with id 2 will break in a new line... how to avoid this?

Comment: either change the width of the inner containers to 50% or increase the width of the outer container to 400px

Comment: I agree with @Pete the most logical solution is to make the inner containers fluid, so that they can scale to the width of your container.  That said however, how is the container element getting it's width attribute?  Are you setting it, or is it being generated dynamically based on some other rules/parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `display: inline-block;` on the inner DIVs and `white-space: nowrap;` on the container, I believe it'll have the desired effect...

HTML

```html
<div class="relative">
    <div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#one, div#two {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/8F4W5/) colorfully demonstrates the result.

Comment: I would also add `white-space:normal;` to the inner divs

Comment: exactly what i wanted :) ty

Answer (score 1):

Use *white-space: nowrap* on the parent div; and use *display:inline-block* for the inner divs.

```
<div style="position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;overflow:scroll;white-space: nowrap">
    <div id="1" style="display:inline-block; width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="2" style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do what Pete suggested you to do, or (since I noted you put an `overflow:scroll` rule, i suppose it's okay if we scroll inside the main div) create another wrapper element with a huge width, to accomodate the two inner ones.

**Here's the fiddle:**   http://jsfiddle.net/dhs8D/

**HTML:**

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;overflow:scroll">
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="one" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
     <div id="two" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:50px;float:left;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#one{
    background-color: red;
}
#two{
    background-color: blue;
}
#wrapper{   
    width: 10000px;
}
```

Comment: this is the closes to what i need. But i dont want to have a static wrapper with 10000px... it should be resizing to all inner elements